# Radio button clicks change function

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

We have two radio buttons when we change the button need to call function. Below is my code.

```
<input id="ordertype" type="radio" align="top" name="ordertype" value="NEW ORDER" checked="">
<input id="ordertype" type="radio" align="top" name="ordertype" value="ADDITIONAL ORDER (add items to previous order)">
```

Jquery code

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    $('input:radio[name="ordertype"]').change(function(){
        if($(this).val() === 'ADDITIONAL ORDER (add items to previous order)'){
           var removepages = 'boothlightingDiv';
        }else{
            var removepages =  'furnishingsprovidedDiv';
        }
    });
});
```

Call function `ToggleDiv('boothsizeDiv', removepages);`

Based radio button need to change the ToggleDiv function parameter.Any help?

Comment: So what is the problem, just call this function.

Comment: not able replacing the variable removepages on ToggleDiv()

Comment: protip: `this.value`

Comment: No toggle in your source code, your var removepages doesn't seem to do anything either.

Comment: use `click` not `change`

Comment: @SterlingArcher Pretty bad advice.

Comment: That's debatable @dfsq

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/f83s4r0j/

Comment: @Medoju, can you please explain in simple words what are you trying to do, and what exactly is the problem?

Comment: my code two radio buttons, default new order radio button is checked, if new order radio button checked my function needs to look like ToggleDiv('boothsizeDiv', 'furnishingsprovidedDiv'); else ToggleDiv('boothsizeDiv', 'boothlightingDiv');

Comment: @MedojuNarendar so what is the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would do something like this:
http://jsfiddle.net/bobrierton/5Lc17p1t/1/

```
    $(document).on('change', 'input[name=ordertype]', function() {

    var value = $(this).val();

    if (value == "ADDITIONAL ORDER (add items to previous order)") {
        //whatever your trying to do
        var removepages = 'boothlightingDiv';
    }else{
        //or whatever your trying to do
        var removepages = 'furnishingsprovidedDiv';
         }
    alert(removepages)
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

instead of `$(this)` use `$('input:radio[name="order type"]:checked')` to access the one that is checked, because when one changes, they both change.